# not able to get xpath value from soapui

Tags: xpath, soapui

I am not able to get xpath value "MatchFound" for the below xml in soapui .
I am trying property transfer functionality .

I tried following XPath :

```
declare namespace ns0='http://KYC/';
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/BarclaysCustomerValidationResponse/oCasaDetailByRefNoDetails/oCasaStatusByRefNoDetails/oRiskProfileClientData/oGetFraudInformationData/oAddressVerificationDetails/ns0:matchedFound
```

**XML :**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <BarclsCustomerValidationResponse xmlns="http://BHKYC/BarclaysCustomerValidation.tws">
         <oCasaByIdNoDetails>
            <ns0:casaByIdNoResults xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">
               <ns0:item/>
            </ns0:casaByIdNoResults>
         </oCasaByIdNoDetails>
         <oCasaDetailByRefNoDetails/>
         <oCasaStatusByRefNoDetails/>
         <oRiskProfileClientData/>
         <oGetFraudInformationData/>
         <oAddressVerificationDetails>
            <ns0:enquiryid xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">51644325</ns0:enquiryid>
            <ns0:enquiryresultid xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">52146422</ns0:enquiryresultid>
            <ns0:matchedFound xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">false</ns0:matchedFound>
            <ns0:numberOfMatches xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">1</ns0:numberOfMatches>
            <ns0:firstMatchUpdatedDate xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">2016-03-31</ns0:firstMatchUpdatedDate>
            <ns0:secondMatchUpdatedDate xmlns:ns0="http://KYC"/>
            <ns0:mostRecentAddressIsMatched xmlns:ns0="http://KYC">false</ns0:mostRecentAddressIsMatched>
         </oAddressVerificationDetails>
         <oCasaPS/>
         <pid>21691</pid>
      </BarclsCustomerValidationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: the namespace uri you declared for ns0 contains a trailing `/`, the namespace in the document doesn't

Comment: The following can be your xpath "//BarclsCustomerValidationResponse/oAddressVerificationDetails/ns0:matchedFound". The best practice is to mask names spaces. Now it looks like "//BarclsCustomerValidationResponse/oAddressVerificationDetails/*:matchedFound"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the problems :

- namespace URI assigned to `ns0` in the XPath/XQuery doesn't match the one in the XML
- the XML has *default namespace* declared at `BarclsCustomerValidationResponse` element. This means `BarclsCustomerValidationResponse` and all the descendant elements without prefix are in the same namespace. You need to declare another prefix, map it to the default namespace URI, and use the prefix accordingly in the XPath

The following works for me :

```
declare namespace ns0='http://KYC';
declare namespace d='http://BHKYC/BarclaysCustomerValidation.tws';
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';

/soapenv:Envelope
/soapenv:Body
/d:BarclsCustomerValidationResponse
/d:oAddressVerificationDetails
/ns0:matchedFound
```

Demo: http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/b8f1f1e9e0c64af37a2e398d5b911569

Answer (score 0):

`BarclaysCustomerValidationResponse` is in namespace `http://BHKYC/BarclaysCustomerValidation.tws`, so your XPath expression `/BarclaysCustomerValidationResponse/` cannot find it. Same goes for its child elements unless they have a particular namespace prefix like `ns0:`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reading XML in SoapUI, you do not need to bother with namespaces. As you have discovered, they make the XPath unnecessarily complicated. For your case, something as simple as this will suffice.

```
//*:matchedFound
```